# Capture value out of query string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string

I am trying to select just what comes after `name=` and before the `&` in :

```
"/pages/new?name=J&return_url=/page/new"
```

So far I have..

```
^name=(.*?).
```

I am trying to return in this case, just the `J`, but its dynamic so it could very several characters, letters, or numbers.

The end case situation would be allowing myself to do a `replace` statement on this dynamic variable found by regex.

Comment: What does `^` do? What would prevent it from working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Way overkill Alvaro. And definately not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`/name=([^&]*)/`

- remove the `^` and end with an `&`

---

Example:

```
var str     = "/pages/new?name=J&return_url=/page/new";
var matches = str.match(/name=([^&]*)/);
alert(matches[1]);
```

---

The better way is to break all the params down (Example using current address):

```
function getParams (str) {
   var queryString = str || window.location.search || '';
   var keyValPairs = [];
   var params      = {};
   queryString     = queryString.replace(/.*?\?/,"");

   if (queryString.length)
   {
      keyValPairs = queryString.split('&');
      for (pairNum in keyValPairs)
      {
         var key = keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[0];
         if (!key.length) continue;
         if (typeof params[key] === 'undefined')
         params[key] = [];
         params[key].push(keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[1]);
      }
   }
   return params;
}


var url    = "/pages/new?name=L&return_url=/page/new";
var params = getParams(url);
params['name'];
```

---

### Update

Though still not supported in any version of IE, [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) provides a native way of retrieving values for other browsers.

Comment: This captures `name=` I want just what would appear after `name=` and before the `&`

Comment: Show the rest of your code.  If you assign it to an array, the array will contain matches, otherwise you'll have to use `RegExp.$1`

Comment: In regards to last update, I'm getting that's not possible to make a regex statement that picks something after a specific character and before another character. Suppose this wasn't a URL and was just a string?

Comment: @Trip: no, the first regex works, you never said how you're assigning it.

Comment: Ah my apologies, vol7ron. :D Terribly sorry. I'm trying to do a replace. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Trip: listed the match example for how to assign.  Note that if `matches` doesn't match anything, it'll be null.

Comment: The function might be overkill, but its necessary if you have duplicate keys, like `name=J&name=K`, which is valid.  Even if there's only one, I still put it in an array so I can handle the results the same way.  Example `for (var n=params['name'].length;n--){ /*... do something with params['name'][n] ... */ }` which will only fail if the key never existed at all.

Comment: The condensed example will miss the final match in the string presented unless a '&' is affixed at the end of the query string.

Comment: @JoshH I'm assuming the *condensed example* is the first 3-line block of code.  I don't think what you're saying is correct: `"/pages/new?name=J".match(/name=([^&]*)/)[1];` returns "J" and there is no ampersand. My `getParams` function should also work as expected.  I think you would need to show an example to see what trouble you've encountered -- also note that it's possible that IE handles regexs different, in case you are using that.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer includes the hash part if there is a hash right after the params. As @bishoy has in his function, the correct regex would be

```
/name=([^&#]*)/
```

Answer (score 12):

Improving on previous answers:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} name
 * @returns {string|null}
 */
function getQueryParam(name) {
  var q = window.location.search.match(new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)'));
  return q && q[1];
}

getQueryParam('a'); // returns '1' on page http://domain.com/page.html?a=1&b=2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var myname = str.match(/\?name=([^&]+)&/)[1];
```

The [1] is because you apparently want the value of the group (the part of the regex in brackets).

```
var str = "/pages/new?name=reaojr&return_url=/page/new";
var matchobj = str.match(/\?name=([^&]+)&/)[1];
document.writeln(matchobj); // prints 'reaojr'
```

Answer (score 4):

here is the full function  (tested and fixed for upper/lower case)

```
function getParameterByName (name) 
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name.toLowerCase() + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search.toLowerCase());
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
\?name=(.*?)&
```

Comment: Hmm this captures `?name=` and I *just* want what would come after `name=` and before `&`

Comment: @pst.. I am not RegEx master yet. :( You mean by variables like $1 or $2 ? I think this example only returns one group

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single line answer that prevents having to store a variable (if you can't use URLSearchParams because you still support IE)

```
(document.location.search.match(/[?&]name=([^&]+)/)||[null,null])[1]
```

By adding in the `||[null,null]` and surrounding it in parentheses, you can safely index item 1 in the array without having to check if match came back with results.  Of course, you can replace the [null,null] with whatever you'd like as a default.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the same result** with simple **.split() in javascript**.

let value = url.split("name=")[1].split("&")[0];

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```js
\??(.*=.+)*(&.*=.+)?
```

Comment: There are other answers (and a accepted one) that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.