# How to call javascript function in <src>?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to call javascript functions in "src" also for

```
<input type=text>
```

I am using a function which returns querystring parameters

```
function GetUrlValue(VarSearch) {
            var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++) {
                var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
                if (KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch) {
                    return KeyValuePair[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

like if:

> "www.testweb.com?a=521&b=http://demo.sacredpixel.com/redsky/wp/modern/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/gd-1.jpg"

so it will return on

`alert(GetUrlValue('a'));` ===> 521

but what i need is to call this function in img and input type 'text'
 tags.. like:

```
<iframe src="" id="well" width="100%" height="100%" />
<input type="text" value="" />
```

How to call function in above two?

Comment: sorry it is not clear... can you explain again

Comment: i just need to call above function in input and iframe tags.

Comment: use jquery, write your function GetUrlValue, receive the value of "b" and put it in like $('#well').attr('src',b); I hope you get an idea...

Comment: when do you want to use it and what is the expected result

Comment: actually i have a single page "Blog-post", and whatever value came in querystring, i will get that value by using above function, now all i need is to call this function so that my iframe and input are loaded on the start of page.

Comment: disappointed :( . anyway thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this type of working. Please review it and let me know.

HTML:-

```
<img id="myimg" src="" />  
<input type="text" id="inputfield" value="">
```

JS:-

```
 function GetUrlValue(VarSearch) {  
        var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);  
        var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');  
        for (var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++) {  
            var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');  
            if (KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch) {  
                return KeyValuePair[1];  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    document.getElementById('myimg').src = GetUrlValue('b');  
    //"http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3html.gif";  
    document.getElementById('inputfield').value = GetUrlValue('a');
```

Host the files and try this url:- 
"www.testweb.com?a=521&b=http://demo.sacredpixel.com/redsky/wp/modern/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/gd-1.jpg"

It worked for me. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @IsbahKhan: Great! You can always select as answer if you find the above answer helpful. It helps other to find it quick.

Comment: @IsbahKhan : One more thing. I have voted your answer. I think now you have enough reputation to post images as well as to vote for an answer. :)
Enjoy coding..

Comment: @IsbahKhan Hello, If this answer is working for you then please tick as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify function **GetUrlValue** with two parameters?
This approach will solve your problem.
Pass the search id and in which text you want to find it.
There is another approach hope you will get help from it.
Following Link will be help you 
[ClickHere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126956/capture-value-out-of-query-string-with-regex)