# dynamically grab value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have generated unordered list which contains values (date representation)
which I want to grab dynamically.

Html source looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li style="padding-left:7px;"> 
        <a href="/Repp/ByDay?day=20140808&amp;sport=0&amp;competition=0">fri 08.08.14</a>
        <a class="..." target="_blank"...></a>
    </li>
```

I want to grab value **20140808** between

```
<a href="/Repp/ByDay?day=
```

and

```
&amp;sport
```

UPDATE

**I want to grab first value from this unordered list.**

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126956/capture-value-out-of-query-string-with-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a good case for regular expressions. In jQuery-terms

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*day=(.+?)&.*$/,'$1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li style="padding-left:7px;"> 
  <a href="/Repp/ByDay?day=20140808&amp;sport=0&amp;competition=0">fri 08.08.14</a>
  <a class="..." target="_blank"...></a>
</li>
```

But if you can alter the HTML just add a data attribute containing your string:

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  alert($(this).data('day'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-day="20140808" href="/Repp/ByDay?day=20140808&amp;sport=0&amp;competition=0">…</a>
```