# Unserialize a request string to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript, if you `serialize()` a key/value array pair, then you'll get something like `single=Single&multiple=Multiple`. Is there any way to "unserialize" this string to get an array of key/value pairs again? If not, what's the most efficient way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6487719/1568059 - maybe this answers your question.

Comment: What did your data structure look like, are you sure you had and array and not an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126995/183181

```js
var str = 'single=Single&multiple=Multiple';
console.log( getParams(str) );


function getParams (str) {
   var queryString = str || window.location.search || '';
   var keyValPairs = [];
   var params      = {};
   queryString     = queryString.replace(/.*?\?/,"");

   if (queryString.length)
   {
      keyValPairs = queryString.split('&');
      for (pairNum in keyValPairs)
      {
         var key = keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[0];
         if (!key.length) continue;
         if (typeof params[key] === 'undefined')
         params[key] = [];
         params[key].push(keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[1]);
      }
   }
   return params;
}
```

Comment: I think you should mark the question as a duplicate instead of reproducing the same answer.

Comment: @trincot I think you're right ;) Though, until it's determined how exactly he would expect the data to be formatted, I'll also leave this here